# Hibernate creating a table that doesn't exist

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am working with intelij, java, spring and hiberante to create tables in my mysql database. My code executes without a problem but for some reason hibernate creates a table I deleted. The table connected two entities with many to many relation with a composite key. One entity was deleted and so the composite key table was also deleted because it was no longer needed. I updated the other table so there is no leftover connections. I tried changing hibernates ddl-auto from update to create. It drops all and creates all with that table that doesn't exist. I also droped the whole schema in mysql workbench multiple times. I am assuming there is some leftover data somewhere in hibernate but I cannot find it especially since the same code works on another computer where it doesn't create the deleted table.

Tis is the hibernate part from my application properties:

```
# Hibernate properties
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Below is the entity that I didn't delete that was connected to the projection_seat_list which doesn't exist anymore as well as the seat entity:

```
@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "projections")
public class Projection {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int projectionId;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private String date;

    @Column(name = "startTime")
    private String startTime;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idHall")
    private Hall hall;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idMovie")
    private Movie movie;

    @Column(name = "seatList")
    @ElementCollection
    private List<Integer> seatList;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "projection", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Ticket> ticketList;

}

This is the part of the output code regarding the problem when app is executed:

Hibernate: drop table if exists `projection_seat_list`
Hibernate: drop table if exists `projections`

Hibernate: create table `projection_seat_list` (`projection_id` integer not null, `seat_list` integer) engine=MyISAM

Hibernate: create table `projections` (`id` integer not null, `date` varchar(255), `start_time` varchar(255), `id_hall` integer, `id_movie` integer, primary key (`id`)) engine=MyISAM


Hibernate: alter table `projection_seat_list` add constraint `FK8rkfyw0lua4jjaamrw3kl3llo` foreign key (`projection_id`) references `projections` (`id`)
```

Here is my whole code on github if you'd like to see the structure:

https://github.com/denibakulic/Java.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake because I had a list in my projection model and with that automatically another table is created because you can't have a list. I got confused because the name of the created table of the same of the one that I previously deleted.